# How to extract the value of the pair retuned by unordered_map::emplace?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to make my code 1 line shorter, a noble cause. I have this unordered map

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> um;
```

and I want to assign the integer to a variable on the same line where I emplace a pair into the unordered map like so

```
int i_want_132_here = um.emplace("hi", 132).first.???;
```

problem is, I have no idea what to do with [return value of unordered_map::emplace].first

In the debugger I can see that "first" contains ("hi", 132) but how do I access those values?

Comment: `int i_want_132_here = um.emplace("hi", 132).first->second;`

Comment: @Borgleader na the .second shows up as "true" in debugger and is supposed to indicate the success of emplacement according to documentation, of course I have no clue how to access the "true" as a boolean value either

Comment: @RetiredNinja correct!

Comment: @user81993 Yeah I missed that, which is why I deleted the comment, was about to post [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d19cd609bf5fc27d) but a Ninja beat me to it.

Comment: You would access the bool the same way. `bool inserted = um.emplace("hi", 132).second;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emplace` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`.

So you should do:

```
int i_want_132_here = (*um.emplace("hi", 132).first).second;
```

alternative syntax:

```
int i_want_132_here = um.emplace("hi", 132).first->second;
```

In general I prefer `(*it)` form instead of `it->`.

Comment: sorry, I fixed my answer

Comment: Why not `->` then.

Comment: @riv Iterators have syntax similar to pointers. `it->value` and `(*it).value` are the same thing.

Comment: @riv I know the arrow operator `->` is also usable but in general I prefer the `(*it)` form